# Shape cannot be defined for the placeholder in Jetpack Compose when using AsyncImage

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a grid list containing photos that load asynchronously. That's why I used AsyncImage, and all of them should have a cicleshape. However, when I use 'contentscale.crop', the placeholder does not become circular. If I don't use crop, the photo printed with AsyncImage is also not circular. I couldn't establish a structure that satisfies both.

```
 AsyncImage(
            modifier = Modifier.clip(CircleShape),
            ...,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            placeholder = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_search)
        )
```

One of the things I actually wanted to ask is why an image I set as a circle does not appear as a circle in the image grid. Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Edit: My list code below

```
LazyVerticalGrid(
                        columns = GridCells.Fixed(3),
                        content = {
                            items(uiState.list.orEmpty()) {
                                CircleImage(url = it.url, modifier = Modifier
                                    .clip(CircleShape)
                                    .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                                    .clickable {
                                        viewModel.register( deviceId = context.deviceId(), avatarIdUrl = it._id,)
                                    })
                            }
                        })
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your case but I would give this a try:

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        //Your preferred image size
        .size(30.dp)
        .clip(CircleShape),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    AsyncImage(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        ...,
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        placeholder = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_search)
    )
}
```